# Display all records with a certain element in lists

Tags: list, erlang

How to use lists:member(User,users) in the match_object command?? 
I have several records in which "users" is a list contain different users , i want to display the records which contain a certain user .

```
find(User) ->
mnesia:transaction(fun () -> 
 case mnesia:match_object(#updt{**users==[User]**, _='_'}) of
    [Y] ->io:format("Records found for the user : ~p~n", [Y]);
    [] ->  io:format("No group found with the user : ~p ~n",[User])
end
end).`
```

Comment: What do your records look like inside Mnesia? I can't tell much from this code, but I'm not sure why you're not using `mnesia:read/1`? Can you show how the table was created?

Comment: {atomic,[{updt,7,["ret"]},
         {updt,6,["aas"]},
         {updt,4,["adlf"]},
         {updt,1,["adlf","lojer","iowef"]},
         {updt,2,["sfdgbs","5rf","grwg","irg"]},
         {updt,3,["adlf"]},
         {updt,5,["aas"]}]}                   so basically i want it to display the enteries in the table which contain for eg "adlf" , so it should be able to show me row no 1 , 3 , 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use match_object. I have answered a similar question:

[answered question][1] https://stackoverflow.com/a/28762454/

Basically you can query the database like you would with a SQL DB using the method i specified in the answered question. You can use lists:member/2 to find matches.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you are doing in a `mnesia:match_object/1` is supplying a pattern to match, no more no less. And in a pattern you can only match data and cannot specify a call to a function. As erlang does not have a patten data type we fake it by supplying a structure which is interpreted as a pattern.

Unfortunately using `mnesia:select/2` will not help here. While a match spec has a "guard" you are only allowed to do typical guard things in it and calling general functions are not allowed.

Note that both `mnesia:match_object/1` and `mnesia:select/2` return the whole objects which match.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 options to solve your problem:

use

```
mensia:foldl(fun({updt,I,L},Acc) -> 
                case lists:member(User,L) of
                    true -> [I|Acc];
                    _ -> Acc
                end,[],Table)
```

or maintain a second table which records what you need ({new_table,User,[I...]})

You should choose depending on the frequency of update request, query request, the size of the table and if there are concurrent accesses or not.